# Number of differences between columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, comparison, sequence

I have a data frame with sequences as columns and amino acid sites as rows. I would like to compare the difference between these sequences at each site.

```
        seq1 seq2 seq3 seq4 seq5 seq6 seq7 seq8   
1      K    E    K    K    A    A    A    A
2      V    D    A    A    T    A    A    A
3      W    W    W    W    W    W    W    W
4      R    R    R    R    R    R    S    R
5      F    S    F    F    F    Y    F    F
6      P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P
7      N    N    N    C    N    N    N    N
8      V    I    D    D    Q    Q    Q    Q
9      Q    Q    Q    Q    Q    Q    Q    Q
10     E    E    G    G    L    I    S    F
11     L    L    Q    L    L    L    L    L
12     N    N    Y    Y    V    V    S    S
13     N    N    N    N    Q    Q    P    P
14     L    L    L    L    L    L    L    L
15     T    T    T    T    T    T    T    I
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to have an additional column in my data frame that shows me the sites that are the same in all sequences and those that are the same only between seq1-4 or seq 5-8.

I am not sure what the best way to do this is, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, is there a way to add another column that shows the types of amino acids observed at each site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will also want to include the code that you used when attempting this problem yourself, along with the desired result.

Comment: Hint:  Coerce to a character matrix and use `rowSums()` with `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to create the flags that you mentioned. Assuming the dataframe is called amino:

```
amino$first_flag<-with(amino,ifelse(seq1==seq2 & seq2==seq3 & seq3 == seq4,"same","diff"))
amino$second_flag<-with(amino,ifelse(seq5==seq6 & seq6==seq7 & seq7 == seq8,"same","diff"))
amino$total_flag<-with(amino,ifelse(first_flag=="same" & second_flag=="same" & seq1==seq5,"same","diff"))
```

Hopefully that works.

edit: and for your last question, I'm not sure what you mean but if you just want the letters that appear in each row then something like this could work:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(amino)) amino$types[i]<-paste(unique(amino[i,1:4,drop=TRUE]),collapse=",")
```

It will give you a column containing a comma separated list of the letters that appeared in each row.

**edit2**: If you have significantly more than 8 sequences, then a modified form of Ganesh's solution might work better (his output code isn't actually necessary):

```
amino$first_flag <- apply(amino[,1:4],1,function(x){
    ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,"same","diff")
})
amino$second_flag <- apply(amino[,5:8],1,function(x){
    ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,"same","diff")
})
amino$total_flag <- apply(amino[,1:8],1,function(x){
    ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,"same","diff")
})
amino$types <- apply(amino[,1:8],1,function(x) paste(unique(x),collapse=","))
```

And for your new question-

```
amino$one_diff <- apply(amino[,1:8],1,function(x){
    ifelse(7 %in% as.data.frame(table(x))[,2,drop=TRUE],"1 diff",NA)
})
```

This uses the table() function which normally gives you a count based on a vector or a column like table(amino$seq1). Using apply, we instead stick a row of the 8 sequences into it, it returns the counts, then we use as.data.frame and the brackets [] to get rid of some extra table() output that we don't need. The "7 %in%" part means if there are 7 of the same letters then there must be 1 different one. Anything else (i.e., all 8 same or more than 1 difference) will get NA.

Comment: I just have one last question (sorry I am still new at using R), if I wanted to know the sites were seq1-4 are the same (e.g. all seq 1-4 have K at a site) and seq5-8 are the same in all but 1 sequence e.g. (all have N except seq5 which has L at that site)  can you think of a better way of doing it other than: ifelse(seq1 != seq2 & seq2 == seq3 & seq3 ==seq4 & seq5 == seq6 & seq6 ==seq7 & seq7 ==seq8, "1 diff", 
 ifelse(seq1 != seq2 & seq1 == seq3 & seq3 ==seq4 & seq5 == seq6 & seq6 ==seq7 & seq7 ==seq8, "1 diff" ... ? thank you

Comment: @NY3 see edit2 above, in my main answer, for the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am first getting an array where all columns are same:

```
allsame <- apply(df,1,function(x){
 val <- ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,1,0)
})
```

Next I am getting an an array where either of the column sets are same

```
startfour <- apply(df[,1:4],1,function(x){
  val <- ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,1,0)
})
lastfour <- apply(df[,5:8],1,function(x){
  val <- ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1,1,0)
})
gen <- startfour + lastfour
eithersame <- ifelse(gen == 0,0,1)
```

Finally you can just create a column vector as required and join it to the dataframe using the above 2 arrays

```
output <- as.character(length(allsame))
for(i in 1:length(allsame)){
if(allsame[i] == 1){
   output[i] <- "all same"
}
else if(eithersame[i] == 1){
   output[i] <- "either same"
}
else{
   output[i] <- "none same"
}
}
df <- cbind(df,output)
```

Comment: Your solution may not work for the original poster... he or she is comparing letters, but using var(x)==0 only works for comparing numbers, not letters.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me. When I tried to do the first step I got this message: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: I am upvoting you since I incorporated part of your solution (slighly modified) to answer another question from the original poster. Note that your output code isn't necessary, you can have apply() add its output directly to the original dataframe, see my edit for details.